# Modal sheet window not centered

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to open a sheet window on my cocoa app:

```
MyWindowController *controller = [[MyWindowController alloc] init];

NSWindow *window = [NSApp mainWindow];

[NSApp beginSheet:controller.window modalForWindow:window modalDelegate:self didEndSelector:nil contextInfo:nil];
```

The problem is that the sheet is not attached to the current window, instead it's shown in the bottom left of the screen. I've tried to use self.view window but nothing changed. What should I do to have the sheet positioned at the top-enter of my window?

Comment: have you checked that the `window` variable is pointing to your main window? You can put an NSLog trace or go into with the debugger...

Comment: I checked for [window title] and it's the right one.

Comment: Is the sheet window from a nib/xib?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure that `Visible At Launch` is unchecked for your sheet window.

Comment: If you can help me for this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275950/show-window-as-sheet-at-specific-location