# How to show an NSWindow as sheet at specific location

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, cocoa-sheet

I have a window like this, having 3 subviews, each one of them has button. On click of those- I need to show sheet.

[image]

[image]

By using this code, sheet comes in centre of the window.

```
- (IBAction)closeSubWindow:(id)sender{
    [NSApp endSheet:self.subWindow];
    [self.subWindow orderOut:nil];
    
}

- (IBAction)showSubWindow:(id)sender {
    [NSApp beginSheet:self.subWindow
       modalForWindow:self.window
        modalDelegate:self
       didEndSelector:nil
          contextInfo:nil];
}
```

**Is there any option or way to show the sheet at specific co-ordinates?**

EDIT:

My current implementation is by using `NSPopover`. Can I make this `NSPopover` to animate like sheet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the `NSWindow` delegate method [`-window:willPositionSheet:usingRect:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSWindowDelegate/window%3awillPositionSheet%3ausingRect%3a)

Comment: This reads promising, I will check this tomorrow. And will update you.

Comment: It Worked. And I need another help.  Is there any way to make sheet modal-less. As I need, sheet should be empty no button on it. To close the sheet the **V** button will work like switch/toggle from **^** and vice-versa. In real implementation there are images on the button.

Comment: Nope, you'll need to roll your own for that (or use a popover as Mike suggested).

Answer (score 0):

A sheet is per definition that what you see. So no, there is no way to place it at a different position. You could create an own implementation, but maybe it is better in your situation not to use a sheet but e.g. an [NSPopover](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSPopover_Class/Reference/Reference.html). This is availabe since OSX 10.7 and a great means to have a temporary view for displaying/entering values. By using the transient (or semi-transient) style the framework takes care for managing the display (automatically hiding the popover when no longer needed). Of course you can also have an OK button on it to commit changes.

The popover is also kinda modal, just like the sheet, so, functionally they are quite similar, but you have more freedom regarding its position.

Comment: Currently it is implemented using NSPopover. But the animation effect similar to Sheet is required. Therefore I am looking for sheet kind of thing.

Comment: Then you have to roll your own implementation.